# include só é inserido depois o <body>, e gostaria que fosse incluído antes

Tags: php, html, include

Uso um arquivo chamado `head.php` para adicionar as meta tags em cada pagina de forma mais facil! Porem o include só é incluído após o `body`, quando na verdade eu preciso que fique antes do `body`!

Codigo base: ...........................................
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo base da pagina head.php
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim que fica no navegador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse espaçamento e aspas estão estranhos. Até seu `código base` está tabulando errado. Você está usando algum *template engine*?

Comment: Tens outros includes na página? O conteudo de `head.php` é somente o que mostras-te? não tem mais nenhuma linha a cima ou em baixo?

Comment: Nao tem nada!! è exatamente isso dai! tanto que tirei print

Comment: Não percebi porque é que está para fechar, se ainda não tem solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi direito sua dúvida, mas segue um exemplo:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <?php include "metas.php"; ?>
   </head>
   <body>
     ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: faço exatamente isso! só que nao da certo!

Comment: @ivanveloso adiciona seu código na pergunta, para te ajudarmos.

Comment: pronto! Adicionei imagens! Para ver exatamente o que acontece!

Comment: Segue algumas considerações:

O include_once, só permite que você inclua este arquivo uma vez; 
Logo, vale verificar se existe alguma outra chamada para esse arquivo no código;

No arquivo head.php, vale verificar se o charset dele está como UTF-8  withou BOOM; 
Se você tiver o notepad++, abra o arquivo e vá no menu Formatar e clique em Converter para UTF-8 sem BOOM.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) juntamente com o `echo`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo file_get_contents('head.php'); ?>
    </head>
</html>
```